# Cropping image into popup?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

How to crop an image coming from server into popup? I have image coming from web service and showing it into a popup on a click on a table. I want to add cropping functionality into it. How can I do it??

Comment: Not quite sure what you're looking for. Do you want to... [A] allow the user to crop the image while displaying it in a popup, [B] Always crop an image when displaying it in a popup.

Comment: i want to allow user to crop image while displaying it in popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of open source image cropping libraries on [cocoacontrols.com](http://cocoacontrols.com) [Here's one](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/ImageCropper) that replicates Apple's crop image feature. You can then display the editing view controller in a popover when the user selects the row.